# Android:How to open pdf?

Tags: android

I try to open pdf, but when I press the button, nothing happens.
Where is my mistake?

```
OnClickListener oclBt2 = new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File("http://testserv1.p.ht/1/ksu016.pdf");

                if (file.exists()) {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);   
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                    } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I corrected my code, but it doesn't work again :( when I press the button, appears the [window](http://piccy.info/view3/4680214/42ec682e5edf79c989461b8eb5ff21a1/)(Sorry, but my reputation doesn't allow to post images)

```
OnClickListener oclBt2 = new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri path = Uri.parse("http://testserv1.p.ht/1/ksu016.pdf");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try {
                startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {               
                mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://hostforandroid.elitno.net/pdf-test.pdf" );
                setContentView(mWebView);
                }               
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `File` is for local files, not `http` URLs. Use `Uri.parse("http://testserv1.p.ht/1/ksu016.pdf");` to get a `Uri` pointing to an `http` URL.

Second, there may be no PDF viewers that are set up to directly download from an HTTP URL. For greater compatibility, you can arrange to download the PDF first (using `DownloadManager` or your own HTTP client code), then view the local PDF file.

Comment: @RostislavShtanko: You do not have a PDF viewer installed that can handle `http://` URLs. I have never tried viewing something from `docs.google.com` and so I cannot comment on why it is failing, other than perhaps you lack the `INTERNET` permission.

Comment: Internet is ok. I didn't undestand about PDF viewer. I think, it installed

Comment: @RostislavShtanko: Again, you may have one that is installed, but one that does not know how to handle `http` URLs directly. Normally, when the user clicks on a link to a PDF in a Web browser, the *browser* downloads the file, *then* launches the PDF viewer to view the local file.

Comment: I downloaded DownloadManager, and now everything is all right. First, the documents is downloading, and after that it opens. Thank you for helping